# Difference between google-map-react and react-google-maps

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps, google-map-react

There are two most popular react abstraction of google maps API(*judging by the weekly npm downloads and github repo stars*). For a beginner like me, it is very confusing as I am not able to decide what can these libraries bring to my project and what not by merely looking at the documentation? 
 
**In short what are the pros and cons of using [google-map-react](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react) and [react-google-maps](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps). I didn't find any comparison on the internet or SO.**

Answer (score 10):

Be carefull, `react-google-maps` project is unmaintained more than a year, see 
https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/986
They suggest to look at [@react-google-maps/api](https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/tree/master/packages/react-google-maps-api) but it is quite a young project and doesn't have a lot of stars on GitHub yet. 
I personally like [google-map-react](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react) which is still under (quite active) development.

Answer (score 2):

I found the google-maps-react documentation a bit confusing because it utilizes a HOC, compose, to simplify the map. For those new to React, it might be easier to start without compose.

react-google-maps, a package that essentially provides a React component wrapper for the Google Maps API. react-google-maps allows users to use the full functionality of Google Maps Javascript API.

Comment: So `react-google-maps` allows users to use full functionality whereas `google-map-react` don't. Correct?

Comment: Yeap and react-google-maps it is much easier integration!